# How do I get requirejs working for thid party library (interact.js)?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd, interact.js

After trying out many things interact.js isn't working with require.js

Here is interact.js file I am using http://code.interactjs.io/interact-1.2.4.js

Since third party library which doesn't 'Define' a module needs to be specified in shim configuration, I tried that:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'scripts',
paths: {
    'interact': 'include/interact.min'
},
shim: {
    'interact': ['include/jquery.min']

}
});
```

I also tried in this way:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'scripts',
paths: {
    'interact': 'include/interact.min'
},
shim: {
    'interact': {
      exports: 'interact'
}

}
});
```

Then trying to use interact function in separate js file like this:

```
define( ['interact'] , function (int) {

 return {
      interact('#renderCanvas').dropzone({});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not look correctly, because it does check whether an AMD loader is present, and calls `define`:

```
// AMD
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('interact', function() {
        return interact;
    });
}
```

I found that by following the link you gave and searching for `define.amd`.

So no `shim`.